# Trying to create a edit function on the todo list from the meteor official tutorial

Tags: meteor

I am currently trying to create an edit button for the todo list on the meteor official tutorial. I am new to meteor so can you please help?

HTML Code:

```
<head>
  <title>Todo List</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <header>
      <h1>Todo List</h1>

      <form class="new-task">
        <input type="text" name="text" placeholder="Type to add new tasks" />
      </form>
    </header>

    <ul>
      {{#each tasks}}
        {{> task}}
      {{/each}}
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>

<template name="task">
  <li class="{{#if checked}}checked{{/if}}">
    <button class="delete">&times;</button>
    <!-- Adding the edit button -->
    <button class="edit">Edit</button>

    <input type="checkbox" checked="{{checked}}" class="toggle-checked" />

    <span class="text">{{text}}</span>
  </li>
</template>
```

My App.js Code:

```
Tasks = new Mongo.Collection("tasks");

if (Meteor.isClient) {
  // This code only runs on the client
  Template.body.helpers({
    tasks: function () {
      // Show newest tasks first
      return Tasks.find({}, {sort: {createdAt: -1}});
    }
  });

  Template.body.events({
    "submit .new-task": function (event) {
      // This function is called when the new task form is submitted
      var text = event.target.text.value;

      Tasks.insert({
        text: text,
        createdAt: new Date() // current time
      });

      // Clear form
      event.target.text.value = "";

      // Prevent default form submit
      return false;
    }
  });

  Template.task.events({
    "click .toggle-checked": function () {
      // Set the checked property to the opposite of its current value
      Tasks.update(this._id, {$set: {checked: ! this.checked}});
    },
    "click .delete": function () {
      Tasks.remove(this._id);
    },
    //trying to figure out how to add the edit function here
    "click .edit": function () {
      Tasks.update(this._id, {});
    }
  });
}
```

I have looked all over the internet to no avail, so I have turned to my last resort, which is stackoverflow. Anyone who is either a veteran or is experienced in this field of meteor, help will me much appreciated!

Comment: Can you clarify what you're trying to do? I don't know what stage you're at in the tutorial, but you can edit items in that example by just clicking on them and typing.  What are you trying to achieve with your button?

Comment: It does not do that for me? Does it do that for you?

Comment: yes, if I run `meteor create --example todos` and run the resulting project, i can just click on the text of an entry and enter what i want.

Comment: This is not the official tutorial on the website. The official tutorial was what I was talking about.